# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-navigation

I am having an error which is showing

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Navigation.navigate')`

i were tried to fix this error but didnt work, I also search the error on network but i am getting other content steps

There My Codes:

```
export const App = ({ Navigation }) => {
/*My Codes*/
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Navigation.navigate("DetailsPage2")>
/*My Object*/
</TouchableOpacity>
```

> I wanted To Switch Pages By clicking on the object using onPress and use arrow function but it shows the error, I tried These Steps to resolve it but it also didnt work These are The steps below which i used to fix the error

`onPress={() => Navigation.getParam("DetailsPage2")` and
`onPress={() => Navigation.push("DetailsPage2")`

I imported all the imports which i need Like

`import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, createRef, useCallback, } from "react"; import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView, TextInput, StyleSheet, Switch, Animated, Dimensions, Vibration, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, } from "react-native"; import { Svg, Path, Defs, RadialGradient, LinearGradient, Stop, Ellipse, Rect, } from "react-native-svg";`

Sorry I Cannot Show My Main Code, If I Show It.

It Could Be Stolen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is occurring because the **'Navigation'** object is not defined in the App component. It is not being imported correctly.

Make sure that the `navigation` object is being passed in as a prop to the App component and that it is being imported correctly.

Replace **Navigation** with **navigation**:

```
export const App = ({ navigation }) => {
 /*My Codes*/
 <TouchableOpacity  
  onPress={() =>  navigation.navigate("DetailsPage2")>
  /*My Object*/
 </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Here is the official doc related to this issue [reference link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating#navigating-to-a-new-screen).
& React Navigation official website for explore more [Link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/).